# Use of Hibernate's openSession() and getCurrentSession() in Single and Multi-threaded environments

Tags: hibernate

Everywhere i have read that in single threaded environment getCurrentSession() is better and in multi-threaded environment openSession() is better? What exactly is the meaning of these statements in easy words? Also, what is really the difference between single and multi-threaded environment?

Comment: Singler-threaded enviroment uses singel thread.Multi-thread uses multiple thread.You can write your components to be executed either in the singel or multi-threade enviroment.If we talk about java,then if your components are going to be accesed from multiple threads(concurrently),then you need to consider thread-safety.Consider the servlets(components for managing HTTP requests).If you use tomcat,it creates single instances of your servlets and then whenever new request arrives,it executes a method on this instance in a new Thread.Hope this helped.Consider reading Java Concurrency in Practice.

Comment: ok, i am gonna ask a more generalized question, if my web application is used by 10 users simultaneously, does it mean that 10 threads are gonna be created/used? Is this multi-threaded environment as multi-users are possible for web-application?

Comment: If you are using a container like tomcat,then tomcat will create 10 threads that will run simultaneously.Each thread will use the same object(Servlet),and this is how most of the servers work.Imagen that we would have a single thread,then while one user is being processed no other can do a request.The multi-threaded enviroment is either created by you(using and starting new thread in application) or by frameworks/tools you use(like Spring,Tomcat,ect).Each thread has its own stack,containing local variables and other useful information.When one thread pauses,another goes in(Context switch).

Comment: Thank you, i think i get your point.